# Refering to this in a function expression in JavaScript,

Tags: javascript

I have a resource object like so:

```
var resource = {
    ...
    All sorts of nifty stuff;
    ...
};
```

I'd like to create a function expression on the fly and refer to other functions in my resource object with the keyword `this`:

```
resource.url = function(){
    return this.constructbaseUrlParams() +
           this.constructReqeustParams();
}();
```

but `this` refers to the `window` object here.

I know I can use:

```
resource.url = function(){
    return resource.constructbaseUrlParams() +
           resource.constructReqeustParams();
}();
```

But I'd like to use `this` so the function can be more modular and perhaps allow me to create multiple resource objects in the future without issue.

#### How can I use this inside my function expression and still refer to my object?

Comment: the value of `this` is totally dependant on how the function is called, not how it was created.

Comment: @adeneo I'm aware. how can I call the functions within whateverObject.url and still refer to whateverObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by how the `function` is called.

And, the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) isn't being called with any associated context object. It's simply defaulting to the global object, `window`.

You can specify the context of the IIFE with [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
resource.url = function () {

    console.log(resource === this); // true

    return this.constructbaseUrlParams() +
           this.constructReqeustParams();

}.call(resource);
```

Comment: I had to google this: IIFE stands for immediately invoked function expression

Comment: ^^^ Give the man a cigar

Comment: You can specify the content or the context of the IIFE?

Comment: @agconti Sorry. Typo. Meant "*context*."

Answer (score 2):

Use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to specify a value for `this` inside:

```
resource.url = function(){ ... }.call(resource);
```

Or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
var fn = function() { ... }.bind(resource);
resource.url = fn();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new `url` function on the object instead of directly invoking it:

```
var resource = {
   foo: function() {
      console.log('foo');   
   } 
};

resource.url = function() {
    this.foo();   
}

resource.url(); //foo
```

Additionally if you want to easily create new instances of a resource with maybe different `url` functions you could move the resource object in a function:

```
function Resource() {
    return {
        foo: function() {
            console.log('foo');   
        }
    }
}

var r1 = new Resource();
var r2 = new Resource();

r1.url = function() {
    this.foo();   
}

r1.url(); //foo
r2.url(); //undefined
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. Making `url` a function instead of a string does.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to tell me. Or lets say I have no idea. Can you extend this a bit?

Comment: You say that "*moving the resource object in a function*" will solve the problem. I say that your solution actually was to make `url` a method - `ressource` could have stayed an object literal.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I was so sure I tried that and it didn't work.  I'll try to improve the answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resource could be turned into a class.

```
function Resource() {
    this.constructbaseUrlParams = function() {
        return "test";
    };

    this.constructReqeustParams = function() {
        return "test2";
    };

    this.url = function() {
        return this.constructbaseUrlParams() +
               this.constructReqeustParams();
    }
};

var resource = new Resource();
console.log(resource.url());
```

Comment: You mean: `url` can be turned into a method?